# Merge or join dataframe in r with some common columns while keeping all rows INTACT and order?

Tags: r

i have a problem:

I have too many dataframe´s and i need to join them, they have some common columns. At this point you can use the function to merge dataframe´s x and y by columns and the others intact, like this:

```
    Merge(x,y,all=T)
```

But the thing is that i need to keep all my rows intact. I cant use rbind(x,y) because some columns arent the same. Im gonna show this with an example:

I have x:

```
                x   y   z
                1   a   11
                2   b   12
                3   c   13
                4   d   14
                5   e   15
```

And y:

```
                   x    y   z   w
                   1    a   11  r
                   2    b   12  s
                   3    c   13  t
                   4    d   14  y
                   5    e   15  u
```

So i need to get a dataframe Q like this:

```
                x   y   z       w
                1   a   11     na
                2   b   12     na
                3   c   13     na
                4   d   14     na
                5   e   15     na
                1   a   11     r
                2   b   12     s
                3   c   13     t
                4   d   14     y
                5   e   15     u
```

Those NA´s can be zero or nothing. How can i do this????? THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plyr)

rbind.fill(x, y)

##    x y  z    w
## 1  1 a 11 <NA>
## 2  2 b 12 <NA>
## 3  3 c 13 <NA>
## 4  4 d 14 <NA>
## 5  5 e 15 <NA>
## 6  1 a 11    r
## 7  2 b 12    s
## 8  3 c 13    t
## 9  4 d 14    y
## 10 5 e 15    u
```